# Predict Monthly Sales for next year

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, prediction

I would like to predict sales for every month for the next year, I have this dataframe:

[image]

I'm trying with

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor()
estimator.fit(X_train,y_train)
estimator.predict(df)
```

But i'm getting this error:

> Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features
>   is 1 and input n_features is 2

Comment: Your training features (input features) are month and year in this case (month, sales_2016) to predict the sales of the next year. And then you are passing (month, sales_2016, sales_2017) so there are 3 input features, which means your estimator doesnt know how to react.

Comment: Why not use time series for this task? It looks like a classical task for time series. Keywords: arma, arima, sarimax.